# Negative lookahead is ignored

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/svOSnY/1

I am trying to match out the memory amount and type form a `Laptop HP Chromebook 14 G3 NVIDIA Tegra SOC 4GB DDRL 32GB FLASH 14inch 1366X768 Webcam Chrome OS`, only, if it is not followed by an additional thing that looks like a memory amount. I thought that negative lookaheads are for exactly this reason:

`(?!\d+\s?(gb|tb))` this is my negative lookahead

As it is applied now:

`/(?:\d+)\s?(?:gb|tb)\s?(?:ddrl|ddr2)\s?(?!\d+\s?(gb|tb))/i`

the `4gb ddrl` part is still matched from my string, even though it is followed by the `32gb` part which my negative lookahead should realise. If I change my negative lookahead, to a simple capture group, my regex correctly captures the whole `4gb ddrl 32gb` part from the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is correct, you just need to move `\s?` into the lookahead. Use `\d+\s*[gt]b\s?ddr[l2](?!\s*\d+\s?[gt]b)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpTgpH/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are declaring the space as optional, the regex egnine will try to match the string without considering the space; and indeed `4GB DDRL` is not *directly* followed by `32GB FLASH` (therefore it will be matched).

In order to fix it, put the optional space in your lookahead:

```
(?:\d+)\s?(?:gb|tb)\s?(?:ddrl|ddr2)(?!\s?\d+\s?(gb|tb))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rsBqes/1).

Comment: It  is not directly because the space is optional. As the space is optional, backtracking triggers and the lookahead check is repeated before a space, where it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

**Backtracking** is a keyword here.

When `\s?` matches a whitespace character, `(?!\d+\s?(gb|tb))` does stumble upon `32GB` and "rolls back" to the previous position, before that whitespace, and since it is a whitespace + `32GB`, the lookahead closes the deal.

Use

```java
\d+\s*[gt]b\s*ddr[l2](?!\s*\d+\s*[gt]b)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/XK2lIA/1). There is no chance the lookahead will re-match here because `1` and `2` have no quantifier.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [gt]                     any character of: 'g', 't'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  b                        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ddr                      'ddr'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [l2]                     any character of: 'l', '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [gt]                     any character of: 'g', 't'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    b                        'b'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```